# POSTMAN continue loading the request forever without any reply

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I am using the native app's latest version and it was working good but suddenly this problem appeared still loading the request without any reply.

[image]

I tried to reinstall it but nothing changed a tried the environment variables for the postman and still the problem. What can I do? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: is your app serving at that port? what does curl say?

Comment: Can you show the code that handles the api call? Your route and controller code.

Comment: Route::get('/events','eventscontroller@index');                                                                   
 contoller method:     public function index()
    {
        $all_events=Event::orderby('id','desc')->get();
        return response(['stauts'=>true,'events'=>$all_events]);
    }

Comment: @ssi-anik yes it is and i test it and was doing well...i do not understand what is curl?

Comment: @mohammedfarhat can you return before the ORM? something like return value to check if it's working or not?

Comment: @mohammedfarhat have you found any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone reading this: problem was that I was not connected to my database. I needed to whitelist my IP address in MongoDB Atlas.

Just so I'm not spamming SO, you can check out my full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263695/11993942

Comment: @sarathsrajendran I was having trouble with my Postman where I would make a POST request and it would be stuck at 'Sending Request'. This thread was one of the first ones I visited when trying to diagnose the problem.