# Can we enable alarm for a service inside the EC2 Instance?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have two EC2 instances, in which I have running Node engine in one EC2 and Mongo in another EC2 instance.

When I am trying to connect with Node instance to Mongo instance it is not connecting. But the Mongo Instance is running.
Later I found that the Mongo is not-working/stopped inside the instance.

Is there any way to know when a Mongo service is not-working/stopped. Like for enabling cloudwatch alarm to know the status of an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AWS Lambda` to write a function to [ping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/ping/) your mongodb, then trigger it by `AWS Cloudwatch` in minutes interval.

Steps:

1. write an api in your node server which is used to [ping mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599543/check-mongoose-connection-state-without-creating-new-connection)
2. write a function to send request to your node server in [AWS Lambda Node](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_tw/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)
3. attach a AWS Cloudwatch to your lambda function in minutes interval

Comment: Hi YuTing,
I am new to AWS Lambda, can you please provide us more information (Lambda Function). it will be very useful .

Comment: i update my ans

Comment: YuTing,
Can you please Lambda function example/reference, how to send request from node instance to mongo instance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: i add an example link about check  mongodb connection by mongoose